# How to pass object to method in select using vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Please check the below code.

```
  <tr>
    <td>Select Timeslot</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <select class="form-control" v-on:change="onTimeSlotClick">
        <option v-for="slot of slots">
          <label slot.time_from - slot.time_to</label>
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I want to pass `slot` object to `onTimeSlotClick` method. How can I do that?
I tried something like `onTimeSlotClick(slot)` but getting `undefined` in `onTimeSlotClick` method.

Comment: to get exact solution please provide and live demo/fiddle ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `v-model` for select tag and set value as object

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    rows: [
      {name: 'MacBook Air', price: 1000},
      {name: 'MacBook Pro', price: 1800},
      {name: 'Lenovo W530', price: 1400},
      {name: 'Acer Aspire One', price: 300}
    ],
    item:""
  },
  methods:{
     onTimeSlotClick: function(item){
       console.log(item);
      }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
   <select class="form-control" v-model="item" v-on:change="onTimeSlotClick(item)">
         <option value="">Select</option>
        <option v-bind:value="row" v-for="row in rows">
          <label>{{row.name}}</label>
        </option>
      </select>
      <div>{{item | json}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a v-model attribute on the select. So...

```
<tr>
    <td>Select Timeslot</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" v-on:change="onTimeSlotClick(selected)">
        <option v-for="slot of slots">
          <label slot.time_from - slot.time_to</label>
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

You can either pass `selected` explicitly, like in the example, or just use the onclick as a trigger, and read `selected` from wherever you defined it in your Vue.

Without knowing your problem, try to avoid event handlers. You can often define what you want with reactive pipes, and your code will be shorter and more expressive.